# How do I get an instance of docker-client from Mac?

Tags: docker

I've a docker running in my Mac which was installed through Home brew. I'm trying to invoke docker remote api through docker-client library. My docker daemon is running fine and exposed at tcp://192.168.99.100:2376. When I try to get instance from docker-client library using http://192.168.99.100:2376 I'm getting invalid scheme exception. How do I map tcp to http ports?

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to do but make sure to read through these docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-socket-option

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at below points.

1. "192.168.99.100" is this your mac machine iP address? have you tried by using localhost:2376?
2. Can you please share the result of **docker ps -a** command? this command should show you which port you are exposing.

Can you please share your docker file?